# Zero-Downtime Deployment with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to obtain zero downtime deployment with Kubernetes. What I have read is that we can obtain this using `readiness-probe` and `RollingUpdate` strategy for `Deployments`. I have tried these two things in my `Deployment.yml` file but everytime I am getting downtime, which I want to avoid. The service is an HTTP based service so I have used `HTTP-Get` probe.

I am using *Helm charts* for the deployment. And I am testing the 0-downtime by redeploying the same code and and same K8s configs.

Given below is the YAML file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: depName
  labels:
    app: appName
    chart: chart
    release: relName
    heritage: relService
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
     app: appName
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate: 
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 1    
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: appName
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: chartName
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 2000m
            requests:
              cpu: 1000m
          image: "repsitoryImage:tag"
          imagePullPolicy: always
          env:
           - name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
             value: dns
           - name: SOME_OTHER_VAR
             value: yasssd
          ports:
           - containerPort: internalPort
             name: someName
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /config
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 15  
            successThreshold: 1
```

Apart from this I have an HPA configured. 
I want the downtime to be zero- which I am not able to achieve.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: I found this article to be very useful https://blog.sebastian-daschner.com/entries/zero-downtime-updates-kubernetes, maybe you need a preStop hook

Comment: thanks @JoshuaOliphant , I will certainly try this and update here.

Comment: @JoshuaOliphant I tried what is given in the blog, basically pre-stop hook. But this also did not help out. I have my java application and nginx for proxying, in the same container. Should I keep two containers, one for java app and other for nginx and make them communicate?

Comment: Seems worth a shot. Are you using a service to load balance to your pods? You might consider using an ingress like traefik and then you wouldn't need nginx in each pod.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. The prehook stop did not work for me. I have readiness probe and prestop hook but still it misses some requests. Did you get it to work ?

Comment: @AnshulTripathi I have also tried several things here, but could not get it working yet.

Comment: I think you need to add a livenessProbe too.

Comment: @morhook that did not worked.